# Click after mouse up outside stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'am drag game scene in Flash project (mouse down - start drag, mouse up - stop drag). If I mouse up outside stage, click on any object (buttons) don't work once. After one click other click works fine. What's wrong?

**update:** Trace logs shown that there event as mouseOver, mouseDown, mouseUp, mouseOut are dispatches, but not CLICK.

**update:** There is silencer of first click after drag in the project. It's necessary to eliminate situation of end drag on some game object (dispath click). Sorry. Thank you all for answers.

Answer (score 1):

You might be losing focus when leaving the stage. Try using `(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE)` to 'force' a mouse_up.

Comment: Вo you mean dispatch mouse up event into mouse leave handler?

Comment: Yeah. I'm afraid I would have to look into it to give more info, but something like that.

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
private var _draggedItem:Sprite;

myDisplayObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

private function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    _draggedItem = event.currentTarget as Sprite;
    _draggedItem.startDrag();
    _draggedItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, stageMouseOutHandler);
}

private function stopDragCurrentItem():void {
    if (_draggedItem) {
        _draggedItem.stopDrag();
        _draggedItem.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
        if (stage) {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, stageMouseOutHandler);
        }
        _draggedItem = null;
    }
}

private function mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    stopDragCurrentItem();
}

private function stageMouseOutHandler(event:Event):void {
    trace("stage out!")
    stopDragCurrentItem();
}
```

**update:**
And concerning the lost focus, you cold do the following in html where you embed your flash:

```
 <object classid="..." codebase="...." width=550 height=400 
         name="myMovie" onmouseover="window.document.myMovie.focus();">
```

though i haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It's already implement. It does not solve problem with first click after mouse up outside stage.

Comment: you should probably return focus to the flash movie on your html page. something like this: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/give-keyboard-focus-embedded-movie.html . so in javascript you could listen to mouseover event (when mouse is over you flash movie container) and manually set focus on it.